# Using 'is' operator to compare two string slices in python

Tags: python, string, memory

I was experimenting with string slicing in python, and this is my code:

```
s = 'a string'
print(id(s[3:]), id(s[5:]))
print(id(s[3:])==id(s[5:]))
print(s[3:] is s[5:])
print(s[3:] is s[3:])
```

The code produced the following results:

```
4396519216 4396519216
True
False
False
```

My question is how those string slices are stored in memory, why do different slices of a string have the same id, and with the same id, why do they yield 'False' when compared using 'is' keyword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you don't save the slices in a variable (or anywhere) after the call to `id`, their lifetime is actually non-overlapping so the `id` may be reused.
from [`id()`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.**

note that because `is` needs them both to live, they probably get different ids, but when you call `id` on each one individually it can be destructed after `id` returns, and the comparison itself is done on the `int` returned from the function.

if you save them to dummy variables, you will get results that are less surprising in my opinion:

```py
s = 'a string'
s3 = s[3:]
s5 = s[5:]
print(id(s3), id(s5))
print(id(s3)==id(s5))
print(s3 is s5)
print(s3 is s3)
```

Output:

```
25517664 25517728
False
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The `==` syntax is comparing the values of the String objects. Technically, it is running the `__eq__` method on the String object.

The `is` syntax compares the objects, not the objects value. When you take a slice of a string you are creating a new object

```
>>> print(id(s[3:]))
139911809265200
>>> print(id(s[3:]))
139911809262384
```

There is something and strange happening with values being returned from the `id` function that I don't understand. However, this `id` issue is a separate thing that doesn't affect how the `==` and `is` syntax works

```
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809262384, 139911809262384, 139911809262384, 139911809262384)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809262384, 139911809262384, 139911809262384, 139911809262384)

>>> a = id(s[3:])
>>> id(a)
139911809261520
>>> b = id(s[3:])
>>> id(b)
139911809261424
>>> c = id(s[3:])
>>> id(c)
139911809261360


>>> (id(a), id(b), id(c))
(139911809261520, 139911809261424, 139911809261360)
>>> (id(a), id(b), id(c))
(139911809261520, 139911809261424, 139911809261360)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809263472, 139911809263472, 139911809263472)
>>> (id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]), id(s[3:]))
(139911809265200, 139911809265200, 139911809265200)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up experiments. I believe this behavior is related to how python creates and stores string slices in memory, but I still have no clue about this detail